# What is Causing this Dart Sq3Lite Database Exception Error?

Tags: flutter, dart

Thank you in advance for your help.

This issue has been driving me crazy for the past couple of days. I have searched every site that Google has returned and still the resolutions haven't helped.

I am attempting to create a Sq3Lite database using Dart and keeping getting a DatabaseException error when trying to create a table that uses foreign keys. I've tried turning foreign key use on with 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON' as well but no luck. I am also using an IOS simulator in Android Studio and delete the app before running the code with attempted fixes.

**Here is my code:**

```
  final int version = 1;
  Database db;

  Future<Database> openDb() async {
    if (db == null) {
      db = await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'skeema.db'), onCreate: (database, version) {
        database.execute('CREATE TABLE Account(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT NOT NULL, CurrencyType TEXT NOT NULL, ' + 'Balance REAL NOT NULL, IsPrimary TEXT NULL)');
        database.execute('CREATE TABLE BudgetItem(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Icon TEXT NOT NULL, Budget REAL NOT NULL, ' + 'IsPrimary TEXT NULL)');
        database.execute('CREATE TABLE TransactionType(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Type TEXT NOT NULL)');
        database.execute('CREATE TABLE Transaction(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Account_id INTEGER NOT NULL, BudgetItem_id INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
            'TransactionType_id INTEGER NOT NULL, Amount REAL NOT NULL, Date TEXT NOT NULL, Party TEXT NOT NULL, Note TEXT NULL, ' +
            'FOREIGN KEY(Account_id) REFERENCES Account(id), ' +
            'FOREIGN KEY(BudgetItem_id) REFERENCES BudgetItem(id), ' +
            'FOREIGN KEY(TransactionType_id) REFERENCES TransactionType(id))');
      }, version: version);
    }
    return db;
  }
```

**Here is the error:**

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "near "Transaction": syntax error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=near "Transaction": syntax error}) sql 'CREATE TABLE Transaction(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Account_id INTEGER NOT NULL, BudgetItem_id INTEGER NOT NULL, TransactionType_id INTEGER NOT NULL, Amount REAL NOT NULL, Date TEXT NOT NULL, Party TEXT NOT NULL, Note TEXT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(Account_id) REFERENCES Account(id), FOREIGN KEY(BudgetItem_id) REFERENCES BudgetItem(id), FOREIGN KEY(TransactionType_id) REFERENCES TransactionType(id))' args []}
#0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:27:7)
#2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.safeInvokeMethod (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:208:15)
#3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.invokeExecute (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:370<…>
```

The first 3 tables get created successfully every time but the last table throws the error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction is a Sq3Lite keyword, so you can't name your table that. So give it any other name and it will work.

There may be ways to use that name anyway if you escape it, but the easy solution is just to choose a different name.

List of all keywords: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it was something simple. The keywords link you posted was one of the pages I researched too. However, I didn't consider my table names when reviewing that list. Just my field names.